# can we use Join, Case and where clause together

Tags: sql

Write a query to display `(product_class_desc, product_id, product_desc, product_quantity_avail )` and show inventory status of products as below, as per their available quantity:

a. For Electronics and Computer categories,

- if available quantity is <= 10, show 'Low stock',
- if 11 <= qty <= 30, show 'In stock',
- if >= 31, show 'Enough stock'

b. For Stationery and Clothes categories,

- if qty <= 20, show 'Low stock',
- if 21 <= qty <= 80, show 'In stock',
- if >= 81, show 'Enough stock'

c. Rest of the categories,

- if qty <= 15 – 'Low Stock',
- if 16 <= qty <= 50 – 'In Stock',
- if >= 51 – 'Enough stock'

For all categories, if available quantity is 0, show 'Out of stock'.

`product_class_desc, product_id, product_desc` are from the `product` table

`product_quantity_avail` is from the `product_overview` table.

Can the case and where clause be used together? `product_quantity_avail` is from another table so will have to do an inner join also.

Can some one help me on how to retrieve this data?

Comment: It's generally better use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the ON and WHERE clauses.

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: Question is not clear, please clarify by adding sample data and expected output.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using case statements and joining the product and product_overview tables.

```
select p.product_class_desc, p.product_id, p.product_desc, 
case when pw.product_quantity_avail = 0 then 'Out of stock' 
     when p.product_class_desc in ('Electronics','Computer') then
          case when pw.product_quantity_avail <= 10 then 'Low stock'
               when pw.product_quantity_avail between 11 and 30 then 'In stock'
               when pw.product_quantity_avail >= 31 'Enough stock' 
          end
     when p.product_class_desc in ('Stationery','Clothes') then
          case when pw.product_quantity_avail <= 20 then 'Low stock'
               when pw.product_quantity_avail between 21 and 80 then 'In stock'
               when pw.product_quantity_avail >= 81 'Enough stock' 
          end
     when pw.product_quantity_avail <= 15 then 'Low stock'
     when pw.product_quantity_avail between 16 and 50 then 'In stock'
     when pw.product_quantity_avail >= 51 'Enough stock' 
     end
from product p
inner join product_overview pw on p.product_id = pw.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use where, case and join together.
If you are using a case condition then you have to rewrite that in where statement if thats the intent.
I guess you are talking about MS-SQL.

e.g.
Select product_class_desc, product_id, product_desc,
case when quantity <= 10 and category = "Electronics" and then "low stock"
when xxxxxxx -- mention all your conditions here one by one
else ...
condition for other categories
end as quantity_status

from table_xx
inner join table_yy on
product_id = productid